How to implement a custom workflow for json deserialization in Rocket framework?
Within the following code I want to allow age to be a number or a string, for example 33 or "33", but it fails when it's a string. How can I accept it? I see process fails before starting the add function. I am using Rocket framework.
#[post("/add", data = "<user_json>")]
#[instrument(name = "user_controller/add", skip_all)]
async fn add(
    app: &AppState,
    mut db: ConnectionDb,
    user_json: Json<UserJson>,
) -> Result<Json<User>, AppError> {

    tracing::info!("==Stating add...");
    let inner = user_json.into_inner();

    tracing::info!("Request to add user. Name: {}, Age: {}", inner.name, inner.age);
    let name = inner.name;
    let age = inner.age;

    if age < 18 {
        return Err(AppError::new(400, "not yet !"));
    }

    let user = app
        .use_cases
        .user
        .create(&app.repos, &mut db, &name, age)
        .await?;
    Ok(Json(user))
}


userJson.rs

use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, FromForm, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct UserJson {
    pub name: String,
    pub age: i32,
}


user.rs

use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use sqlx::FromRow;

#[derive(Debug, FromRow, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct User {
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
    pub age: Option<i32>,
}

Error logs:
INFO rocket::server: POST /users/add application/json:
INFO rocket::server::_: Matched: (add) POST /users/add
WARN rust_rocket_web::controllers::user_controller::_: Data guard `Json < User >` failed: Parse("{\r\n    \"name\": \"Fer\",\r\n    \"age\": \"21\"\r\n}", Error("invalid type: string \"21\", expected i32", line: 3, column: 15)).
INFO rocket::server::_: Outcome: Failure
WARN rocket::server::_: No 422 catcher registered. Using Rocket default.
INFO rocket::server::_: Response succeeded.

